# How to use one distro's live CD to install another distro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, usb, system-installation

I'm trying to install Mint Linux to a USB stick, but the Mint live CD doesn't fit on a normal CD and I don't have any DVDs available. The Ubuntu live CD does fit on a CD, so I want to use the Ubuntu LiveCD to install Mint. Is that possible?

Comment: What is your current operating system? 
And do you mean you want to install Linux Mint to an external USB stick using Ubuntu liveCD, or do you simply want to make a bootable USB stick via Ubuntu liveCD?

Comment: @beirapadua My current OS is Ubuntu LiveCD. I do not have an HDD, so I want to install Linux Mint on an external USB stick from this liveCD

Comment: If Mint has a minimal "network install image", you could use that to install to the external drive

Comment: The Ubuntu livecd does not fit on a cd anymore either.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the target distro you can execute from a different distro one of the setup tools. The most popular tools are:

- [Kickstart](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-howuse.html) (RHEL, CentOS etc)
- [debootstrap](http://linux.die.net/man/8/debootstrap) (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint)

I would suggest to use a Debian or Ubuntu network installation CD, boot a basic system and then use `debootstrap` to bootstrap Mint from it. I am not too familiar with Mint, but I know of its heritage. And since I have successfully bootstrapped Debian from Debian, Ubuntu from Debian and Ubuntu from Ubuntu (all the same architecture, however), I have no doubt this will work with Mint as well.

After bootstrapping you can even `chroot` into the "new" system after bind-mounting `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` from the "host" and then install GRUB and so on ...

Comment: Definatelly an interesting approach. I will try and tell later.

Comment: Now that I am thinking my current live is 32bit and the one I want to install is 64b. So I may try to do this from the usb stick where I have Mint LiveUSB.

Comment: @KiaMorot: in principle this should still work, as `debootstrap` *is* prepared to deal with such cases. However, you may not be able to use the `chroot` method then. So you'll have to boot into the system and can make customizations (other than just editing files) then.

Comment: I could not get it through. I installed the debian base with debootstrap but when I was setting up the /proc dirs I got permission denied which I did not understand as I was root. Due to time requirements I did it the easy way.

Comment: @KiaMorot: "setting up the /proc"? You bind-mounted it while in the `chroot`? You cannot have two `/proc` sit on your system.

Comment: Oohh yeah, that's why I did not understand it. Nevertheless I will setup the same scenario using VMs and tell you.