# How to install Linux distro to a second hdd from within a running Linux Desktop Environment?

Tags: fedora, system-installation, dual-boot, grub2, bootable

More specifically, I am running Fedora18 on my main HDD.  I have a second HDD in the "UltraBay" slot of my ThinkPad W520--eSata connection.

**Is there a possibility to avoid creating a LiveCD/USB, etc, and, perhaps, to directly write the extracted ISO contents of a different distro (Ubuntu) to the second drive; or to use a virtual system as a means of facilitating a "non-live/non-virtual"/REAL installation of an OS?**

There's got to be a better solution than having to deal with the annoying media-creation!
 I'm not too familiar with PXE booting, but it seems that even that adds an extra step of preparing the network server/system for allowing access, etc.

---

### Docs and Resources

> - [Fedora 19: Hard Drive Installation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Installation_Guide/s1-steps-hd-installs-x86.html)
> - [Ubuntu: ISO Boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot)
> - [ArchWiki - Category: Getting and Installing Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Category:Getting_and_installing_Arch)
>
>   - [Archlinux: *Archboot* method](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archboot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to install linux from another linux install. One way is known as *"poor man's install"*. You create a partition, copy the ISO contents there and use GRUB to boot and start the installer from that partition. There are several guides available online, e.g.:

[Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux)

[Debian](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/) (see *Installation media: Hard Disk*)

[Fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/index.html) (see *Preparing for a Hard Drive installation*)

Another way would be to *"bootstrap"* a distro from another distro (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65800/how-to-use-one-distros-live-cd-to-install-another-distro) on U&L) e.g.:

[Archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_Existing_Linux)

[Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/altinstall.xml#doc_chap5)

Comment: If anyone else has some supporting info/sources, please feel free to add it on here.  I'll try to make it more accessible, and easier to find when searching for related issues.  Thanks